# Building wheel for typed-ast (setup.py): finished with status 'error'

Tags: python, docker, pylint

During building of Docker Image I'm facing this issue : **Building wheel for typed-ast (setup.py): finished with status 'error'**
As I'm trying to install pylint but getting here after Dockerfile moves to pylint step.

```
RUN pip install pylint \
&& pylint -E .
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the `clang` package was missing. Installing it solved the issue.